# Square root of a negative array Python

Tags: python, arrays, sqrt, cmath

I know that Python has the cmath module to find the square root of negative numbers.

What I would like to know is, how to do the same for an array of say 100 negative numbers?

Comment: iterate through the array to find the square root for each? Just like you would do for a non-negative array? Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: By `array` do you mean `list`?

Comment: `map(cmath.sqrt, your_array)`?

Comment: @DSM by array, i mean a list containing say 100 numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to iterate over elements of a list and apply the `sqrt` function on it so. You can use the [built-in function `map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) which will apply the first argument to every elements of the second:

```
lst = [-1, 3, -8]
results = map(cmath.sqrt, lst)
```

Another way is with the classic list comprehension:

```
lst = [-1, 3, -8]
results = [cmath.sqrt(x) for x in lst]
```

Execution example:

```
>>> lst = [-4, 3, -8, -9]
>>> map(cmath.sqrt, lst)
[2j, (1.7320508075688772+0j), 2.8284271247461903j, 3j]
>>> [cmath.sqrt(x) for x in lst]
[2j, (1.7320508075688772+0j), 2.8284271247461903j, 3j]
```

If you're using Python 3, you may have to apply `list()` on the result of map (or you'll have a ietrator object)

Comment: Or this can be written as a list comprehension: `[cmath.sqrt(x) for x in lst]`

Comment: Also note that on python 3.x `map` returns a *map object*,  so to turn it back into a list you would need `list(map(cmath.sqrt, lst))`

Answer (score 4):

```
import cmath, random

arr = [random.randint(-100, -1) for _ in range(10)]
sqrt_arr = [cmath.sqrt(i) for i in arr]
print(list(zip(arr, sqrt_arr)))
```

Result:

```
[(-43, 6.557438524302j), (-80, 8.94427190999916j), (-15, 3.872983346207417j), (-1, 1j), (-60, 7.745966692414834j), (-29, 5.385164807134504j), (-2, 1.4142135623730951j), (-49, 7j), (-25, 5j), (-45, 6.708203932499369j)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If speed is an issue, you could use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1+0j, -4, -9])   
np.sqrt(a)
# or: 
a**0.5
```

result:

```
array([ 0.+1.j,  0.+2.j,  0.+3.j])
```